# SIP VoIP Phone app for IOS 10 supporting CallKit and PushKit

Tags: ios, voip

As per the title, I'm looking for an App that supports both CallKit and PushKit that can be provisioned with my own SIP provider.

CallKit is the feature that allows you to answer from Lock Screen like a normal call. 
PushKit allows the calls to come through regardless whether the App is closed / running in the background.

SessionChat is as close as I've come. It supports CallKit but not PushKit.

Groundwire looks as though it might support both but I don't want to pay to trial it.

Answer (score 0):

[Bria](https://www.counterpath.com/ios-sip-softphone/) from Counterpath supports both CallKit and PushKit (needs to be enabled manually in the SIP account's settings).

They have a subscription model with a free trial so you can test it to see if it works with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Groundwire supports Callkit and Pushkit as well.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Your answer has been flag as low quality and might be removed; please have a look at [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/23377) for some tips on how to improve it.